# multiple tables fitted in a single rectangle

Tags: tables

I am trying to report a regression table exactly as it is in State. I generated 3 different tables using the `tabular` code as you can see below.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{l|lrrr}
Source   &  & SS         & df  & MS         \\ \hline
Model    &  & .00570871  & 1   & .00570871  \\
Residual &  & 863.13874  & 892 & .967644327 \\ \hline
Total    &  & 863.144449 & 893 & .966567132
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{llr}
Number of obs       & = & 894     \\
F(1, 892)           & = & 0.01    \\
Prob \textgreater F & = & 0.9388  \\
R-squared           & = & 0.0000  \\
Adj R-squared       & = & -0.0011 \\
Root MSE            & = & .98369 
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{llrrrrrr} \hline
mathsc6 &  & Coef.     & Std. Err. & t     & P\textgreater|t| &        \multicolumn{2}{r}{{[}95\% Conf. Interval{]}} \\ \hline
treated &  & -.0050743 & .066064   & -0.08 & 0.939            &  -.1347333              & .1245847             \\
\_cons  &  & .0196085  & .0487597  & 0.40  & .0688            &  -.0760885              & .1153055        \\ \hline    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there a way to fit the entire table in a single rectangle as in the foto?

[image]

By fitting it, I mean to widen the third table to the entire textwidth. The first two tables together should be as large as the textwidth (that is, the third table). Furthermore the height of the first table should be the same as the height of the second table.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this? This solution uses two top-aligned `tabular` environments in the upper part, followed by a full-width `tabular*` environment in the lower part.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Set up typographic structs:
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.3ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\newcommand{\TB}{\T\B} % top&bottom struts

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r|rrr@{}}
Source\B   & SS         & df  & MS         \\ \hline
Model\T    & .00570871  & 1   & .00570871  \\
Residual\B & 863.13874  & 892 & .967644327 \\ \hline
Total\T    & 863.144449 & 893 & .966567132
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}llr@{}}
Number of obs       & = & 894     \\
F(1, 892)           & = & 0.01    \\
Prob \textgreater\ F& = & 0.9388  \\
R-squared           & = & 0.0000  \\
Adj R-squared       & = & -0.0011 \\
Root MSE            & = & .98369 
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{r}} 
\hline
mathsc6\TB &  Coef. & Std.\ Err. & t~ & P\textgreater|t| 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{[95\% Conf.\ Interval]} \\ 
\hline
treated\T & -.0050743 & .066064 & -0.08 & 0.939 & -.1347333 & .1245847  \\
\_cons\B  & .0196085  & .0487597 & 0.40 & .0688 & -.0760885 & .1153055  \\ 
\hline    
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses

- an outer `tabular` for the positioning of the inner tables,
- package `siunitx` for aligning and printing the number columns,
- normal fonts instead of the typewriter original, and
- tries to detect and set math formulas or variables (not complete).

The example file (the typed tabular data comes from Mico's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426009/16967)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}% or environment "table"
  \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{
      l
      S[table-format=3.8]
      S[table-format=3]
      S[table-format=1.9]
    }
      \toprule
      Source   & {SS}       & {df} & {MS}       \\
      \midrule
      Model    & .00570871  & 1    & .00570871  \\
      Residual & 863.13874  & 892  & .967644327 \\
      Total    & 863.144449 & 893  & .966567132 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{ = }S[table-format=3.5]}% The minus in "-0.0011" is covered by 3 from 3.5
      \toprule
      Number of obs       & 894     \\
      F(1, 892)           & 0.01    \\
      Prob \textgreater\ F& 0.9388  \\
      R-squared           & 0.0000  \\
      Adj R-squared       & -0.0011 \\
      Root MSE            & .98369  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \tabularnewline
    \addlinespace[2ex]
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{%
      \begin{tabular}{
        l
        S[table-format=-1.7]
        S[table-format=1.7]
        S[table-format=-1.2]
        S[table-format=1.4]
        S[table-format=-1.7]
        S[table-format=-1.7]
      }
        \toprule
        mathsc6 &  {Coef.} & {Std.\@ Err.} & {$t$} & {$P>|t|$}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{[\SI{95}{\percent} Conf.\@ Interval]} \\
        \midrule
        treated & -.0050743 & .066064 & -0.08 & 0.939 & -.1347333 & .1245847  \\
        \_cons  & .0196085  & .0487597 & 0.40 & .0688 & -.0760885 & .1153055  \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
    }
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]